# Is there for loop to use each function in php?

Tags: php

```
$max_line_length = 998; // used below; set here for ease in change
reset($lines);
while(list(,$line) = @each($lines)) {
  $lines_out = null;
  if($line == "" && $in_headers) {
    $in_headers = false;
  }
```

Can I use for loop instead of this `while(list(,$line) = @each($lines))`

Comment: Note that `each` no longer exists. It was removed in PHP 8, so that `@` really shouldn't be there: this code should _absolutely_ not hide the warnings =) That said: the docs for Each explain what it does, so writing the corresponding behaviour with a for loop is fairly easy.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I suspect that's why she's looking for a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
foreach ($lines as $line)) {
    $lines_out = null;
    if($line == "" && $in_headers) {
        $in_headers = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want `foreach ($lines as $line)`. [`each()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each) produces a pair (key, value) and the code in the question ignores the key. `foreach ($lines as $line)` ignores the keys; use `foreach ($lines as $key => $line)` to also get the keys.

Comment: @axiac Thanks. I thought he was destructuring the elements of a nested line array. I never use `each()`, and I obviously won't in the future.